# Hidden Terminal Simulation in OMNET++

Tags: collision, ping, omnet++, inet

I am trying to create an environment in oment++ where throughput degradation can be observed due to hidden terminal problem. I have SENT ping messages to same host from two different nodes, hidden from each other using `pingapp` source from `inet`. But hosts are waiting for each other to generate next ping and there is no simultaneous transmission which can cause collision. Here are those lines from my ini file

```
# ping app (host[0] pinged by host[1] and host[2])
*.host[0].numPingApps = 0
*.host[*].numPingApps = 1
*.host[*].pingApp[*].destAddr = "host[0]"
*.host[*].pingApp[0].startTime = 1s
**.pingApp[*].printPing = true
```

I know I need to change some functionality in `pingapp.cc` file but dont know what and how?
Can someone with omnet and inet experience here help me out?

Comment: How did you hide the nodes from each other?

Comment: I have taken three static nodes and placed the hidden ones in out of range while the target is within their range, a common hidden terminal scenario

Comment: Are you referring to the communication range, the interference range, or the detection range?

Comment: I am actually not sure. There are circles drawn around nodes and when one comes within others, they start exchanging messages. so i guess it is communication range. I am quite a newbie in omnet so sorry if it seems shallow.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I would suggest to use ideal radio. To configure wlan this will do the job:

```
**.wlan[*].radioType = "Ieee80211IdealRadio"
**.wlan[*].radio.transmitter.maxCommunicationRange = 100m
```

Now you know the fix communication range of the hosts and you can choose the correct positions for your hidden terminal simulation.